# Need to perform SVN operation

Tags: svn

I am using `TortoiseSVN` to clean up the folders. I want to perform the following actions

- right-click on working copy folder while holding the shift-key down
- choose "delete unversioned items"

either c# code or command line code is acceptable

Comment: Do you want to *delete unversioned items* with command line?

Comment: Yes. need to delete unversioned items optimally in  windows machine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `svn 1.9` you have `--remove-unversioned` option:

```
svn cleanup . --remove-unversioned
```

https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-cleanup-options